# An Ingenious way of connecting two microcontrollers to one sd card

Tags: arduino, buffer, arduino-uno, arduino-ide

I use two 'Arduino Uno' Microcontrollers.
One collects images and the other sensor data.
If I were to use only one 'Uno' for both collections, then each sensor sample will have have to wait 10 seconds for each image.

Since the split, I now want to save the data and images into one SD card. I realize the card can only handle one master at a time. Instead, I feel like the presence of another piece is necessary.

For instance, something that holds sensor data memory temporarily (maybe a IC buffer) that waits for the image to complete saving.

I just do not know what such a device/piece is called. If nonexistent, would there be some other method of accomplishing this dream?

Comment: You could multimaster the SPI bus to the SDcard and handshake access between the two unos but it sounds like you've outgrown the uno.  Consider a more modern arduino solution like the Zero or Due that will process the image faster and simplify the problem.

Comment: You could use an interrupt for the sensor data, and keep the image collector and data writing in the main loop.